# Using post processing effects with box2dlights in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, post-processing

I'm using [libgdx-contribs/postprocessing](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/tree/master/postprocessing) to add a `bloom` effect to shapes in my `libgdx` application.

And [box2dlights](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights) for some lights and shadows.

My goal is to render the box2d world and apply the lights and shadows, then render all the shapes again using the `bloom` effect.

But when I run the code below, I only see the shapes with `bloom` effect. There are no box2d lights or shadows being cast.

Any ideas why?

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    // render box2d lights/shadows
    for (Body body : bodies) {
        ((Shape) body.getUserData()).draw(
                shapeRenderer,
                body.getPosition());
    }

    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(camera);
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();

    // apply post processing effects (bloom)
    game.getPostProcessor().capture();
    for (Body body : bodies) {
        ((Shape) body.getUserData()).draw(
                shapeRenderer,
                body.getPosition());
    }
    game.getPostProcessor().render();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
game.getPostProcessor().enableBlending();
```

In your render method. Apparently [here](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/issues/12) they have the same problem pointing to [this example](https://github.com/manuelbua/libgdx-contribs/blob/master/postprocessing-demo/src/main/java/com/bitfire/postprocessing/demo/PostProcessingDemo.java#L189).

Comment: cheers! this was final solution: `bloom.enableBlending(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);`